# Volley server POST required in JSON whereas it is in the key & value pair format

Tags: android, json, hashmap, android-volley

The code snippet is used with volley library for android networking. And the Map variable params should be a JSON whereas it is in the key & value pair format.

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("\"user\"", "\"abc123\"");
    params.put("\"password\"", "\"passw1234\"");
    Log.d(TAG, "params: "+ params.toString());
    return params;
}
```

Result of params from this is
{"user"="abc123", "password"="passw1234"}

whereas I want the required output from the params as
{"user" : "abc123", "password" : "passw1234"}

Comment: What is the problem? Any questions? replace("=", " : ");

Comment: No in Volley Library - The java class [Request.java]

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('=');
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('&');
            }

Comment: So is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: Just use a jsonobject instead of trying to use a map

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you give me an example of it. That would really be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need quotes. You can remove them.

You should also post the string/error you get from the onRespone()/onResponseError().

I use Volley like this for POST request. The library turns the key & value pair format to JSON.

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("email", "fakeEmail");// 
    params.put("password", "fakePassword");
    return params;
}
```

Afterwards I deserialize the result with GSON.

Comment: I think error 404 means your server is down or your link is broken. Try it on a browser. If it also doesn't work there, then your problem isn't with Volley.